# elasticsearch = cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch as a single node cluster.
One of the indexes is yellow with the explanation below.
I have read all the material here and in general, I did not find a solution for this problem.
here is the index info:
`yellow open research-pdl    8_TrwZieRM6oBes8sGBUWg 1 1 416656058  0  77.9gb  77.9gb`

this command `POST _cluster/reroute?retry_failed` does not seems to be doing anything.

the setup is running on docker, I have 650GB free space.

```
{
  "index" : "research-pdl",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : false,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
    "at" : "2020-12-16T05:21:19.977Z",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate" : "no",
  "allocate_explanation" : "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "5zzXP2kCQ9eDI0U6WY4j9Q",
      "node_name" : "37f65704d9bb",
      "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "67555622912",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "transform.node" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20"
      },
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "a copy of this shard is already allocated to this node [[research-pdl][0], node[5zzXP2kCQ9eDI0U6WY4j9Q], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=J7IX30jBSP2jXl5-IGp0BQ]]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception message is very clear, Elasticsearch never assigns the replica of the same primary shard on the same node for high availability reasons.

> a copy of this shard is already allocated to this node
> [[research-pdl][0], node[5zzXP2kCQ9eDI0U6WY4j9Q], [P], s[STARTED],
> a[id=J7IX30jBSP2jXl5-IGp0BQ]]

**And as you have a single node cluster, so you will not have another other node where your replicas can be assigned.**

**Solutions**

1. Add more nodes to your cluster, so that replicas can be assigned on other nodes. (preferred way)
2. Reduce the replica shards to 0, this can cause data-loss and performance issues. (if at all, you don't have the option to add data-nodes and you want the green state for your cluster).

You can update the replica counts using [cluster update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that I had other indexes and they suddenly disappeared because of using a single node database? I am facing an issue with index total losss. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF, Your cluster state is yellow, which means only replica shards are missing and you don't have a data-loss in your cluster, read more about health API here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

Comment: by adding another node do you mean docker-machine on the same server? or a new virtual server with elastic on it. thanks

Comment: new virtual server with elastic

Comment: You did not understand my first comment. yesterday I had 2 more indices, suddenly they have disappeared. They are not in the _cat/indices. can it be that the fact that I'm using a single node cluster caused them to disapear? thanks

Comment: @SexyMF this is interesting if it's not in _cat/indices, then maybe it deleted and you have the data-loss , but ES cluster should normally turn RED best is to ask a separate question with the logs during that time to keep it focused :)

Comment: this is a docker setup, I dont have logs yet.... I dont know.

Comment: @SexyMF, did you mount the volume of docker container, if not, you can still go inside the docker container and see the logs

Comment: only this is binded: `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` does it have logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319202/elasticsearch-indexes-disappeared-unexpectedly thanks!

Comment: reducing replica count to 0 is not solution. 
I have many data nodes in elasticsearch cluster and my cluster is very large. Yesterday new index got created with 10 shards (5 Primary and 5 Replica) with size of 2.06 TB and the data node size is 2 TB only.
 
What is other solution ?